# Getting unknown server error while initializing GSS security context

Tags: macos, active-directory, gssapi

Working on a cocoa OSX app, Mac bind with active directory and logged in as active-dir user.

Getting the unknown server error while initializing GSS security context: with a PrincipalName provided by the server.

```
gss_init_sec_context
major: unknown routine error
minor: Server (krbtgt/LOCAL@XYZ.LOCAL)unknown while looking up 'WIN-    ****$/xyz.local@LOCAL' (cached   result, timeout in 167 sec)
```

Klist -5 displays these on terminal:

```
Credentials cache: API:DD4CC511-7BE2-4267-9923-6C8ABCD9297D
    Principal: user@XYZ.LOCAL

Issued                Expires               Principal
Nov  5 17:21:23 2015  Nov  6 03:21:23 2015     krbtgt/XYZ.LOCAL@XYZ.LOCAL
```

Because off this error, I changed ker5.conf file like this:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = XYZ.LOCAL
  renewable = true
  forwardable= true
  ticket_lifetime = 20d
  renew_lifetime = 1d
  default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96,  des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5
  default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5


[domain_realm]
 xyz.com = XYZ.LOCAL
.xyz.com = XYZ.LOCAL
```

Comment: Does your implementation support `KRB5_TRACE`?

Comment: Can you please tell me- How to enable that on OSX client for active-directory?

Comment: This is a standard MIT Kerberos environment variable.